# NodeJS and Backbone's fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

This is my front-end code (using `fetch`)

```
    var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
    var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: '/questions',
        model: MyModel
    });
    var coll = new MyCollection();
    coll.fetch({
        error: function (collection, response) {
            console.log('error', response);
        },
        success: function (collection, response) {
            console.log('success', response);
        }
    });
```

and this is my back-end code (using `app.get`)

```
app.get('/questions', function (request, response) {
    console.log('Inside /questions');
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/json'
    });
    response.write('{test:1}');
    response.end();
});
```

The problem is that although the response is as expected, the client-side `error` callback is called. When I remove the line `response.write('{test:1}');`, the `success` callback is called. Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `{test:1}` is not valid JSON.

`{ "test":"1" }`
OR
`{ "test":1 }`
 is however, try one of those instead.

Keys are strings in JSON, and strings in JSON must be wrapped in double quotes check out [JSON.org](http://json.org) for more information.

To ensure you have valid JSON for more complex objects just use `JSON.stringify()`:

```
var obj = { test : 1 };
response.write(JSON.stringify(obj)); //returns "{"test":1}"
```

Also, the [correct Content-Type for json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) is `application/json`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was indeed the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to know more information about the error? In the future I would like to be told that it's the JSON that is invalid...

Comment: I'm not a big `node.js` or `backbone` guy. I would guess that the error response has some information in it though; if not I would post another question, sorry..

Comment: Of course you could always just build a JS object: `{ test: 1 }` and stringify it so that it is always valid: `JSON.stringify({ test: 1 })`

Answer (score 2):

`{test:1}` isn't valid JSON, you should try `{ "test":"1" }`.

Another solution is to check Express's render.json function to see how it does sending json to the browser:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L152-172

Answer (score 1):

If you're using express you need to res.send will automatically convert objects into JSON. If you're worried about it, there's a new one called res.json that will convert anything into JSON.

```
var obj = {super: "man"}
res.send(obj) // converts to json
res.json(obj) // also converts to json
```

You don't need need writeHead(), write(), or end().

http://expressjs.com/guide.html